# Show whether the linear transformation is invertible.

Tags: linear-transformations

Show whether the linear transformation is invertible. $$P:M_{(n,n)}\rightarrow M_{(n,n)},\,P(A)=A+A^T$$

[Sol]Let $T(x)=Bx$ be the inverse linear transformation of P.
Then

$\space \space \space\space\space\space\space$   $T(A+A^T)=A$

$\space \space \space\space\space\space\space$ $B(A+A^T)=A$

$\space \space \space\space\space\space\space$$BA+BA^T=A$

$\space \space \space\space\space\space\space$$BA^T=A(I_n-B)$

This is where I stopped because I don't know how to continue. AM I on the right track? If yes, how to do I continue? Much thanks!

ps: I think this should be not invertible.

Followup: Showing the linear transformation is not injective.

Consider the matrices $C=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 3 & 6 \\
    0 & 8 & 4 \\
    0 & 7 & 5 \\
    \end{bmatrix} ,D=\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    3 & 8 & 7 \\
    6 & 4 & 5 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

$P(C)=C+C^T$

$\space \space \space \space \space\space\space\space\space=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 6 \\
    3 & 16 & 11 \\
    6 & 11 & 10 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

$P(D)=D+D^T$

$\space \space \space \space \space\space\space\space\space=\begin{bmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 6 \\
    3 & 16 & 11 \\
    6 & 11 & 10 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

Thus, $P(C)=P(D)$ but $C\neq D$

Therefore the linear transformation is not injective, and thus not invertible.

Comment: I can't follow your logic. What is $B$? If you think the map is not invertible, you need to provide an explicit counterexample.

Comment: Good call, it's not invertible. Try showing its not injective (come up with a non-zero matrix such that $P(A) = 0$) or that it's not surjective (come up with some common matrix property that all matrices of the form $A + A^\top$ have; you might want to try some specific examples if you can't figure it out).

Comment: @JairTaylor Soz just edited the question. T(x)=Bx

Comment: $P$ is a map between spaces of matrices, so $B$ has dimensions $n^2 \times n^2$, not $n \times n$.  So e.g. $I_n - B$ is not defined.  $BA$ is defined, but only if you "stretch" $A$ out and interpret it as a $n^2 \times 1$ vector instead of a $n \times n$ matrix. You won't be able to find a $n\times n$ matrix $B$ so that $BA = A + A^T$ for every $A$.

Comment: I'd start much more simply.  Write out some examples of $2\times 2$ matrices and see if you can find two of them so that you get the same result under $P$.  Then $P$ would not be invertible.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yep that's what I did before starting to prove that it is not invertible. Does that mean I just have to show that the linear transformation is not injective to prove that it is not invertible? If so giving a counterexample settles it right?

Comment: BTW I don't quite follow your earlier comment about the $n^2\times n^2$ dimension, kinda lost...

Comment: Yup, if it's not injective it's not invertible.  So if you have your counterexample to show it's not injective you are done.

Comment: The space $M_{n, n}$ of matrices has dimension $n^2$ because there are that many entries to fill in.  So then a linear map $M_{n, n} \rightarrow M_{n, n}$ would have to be represented by a $n^2 \times n^2$-matrix.  You don't need that big matrix, though.  It's easier just to think of $P$ as a linear transformation without representing it as a matrix.

Comment: @JairTaylorJust updated the workings for the injective part. Can you check it out for me? Thanks!

Comment: @CJC.10 Perfect!

Comment: @CJC.10 Looks good.

Answer (score 2):

Try the $2\times2$ case.  Take the standard basis, $\{e_{11},e_{21},e_{12},e_{22}\}$.  Then $P(e_{ii})=2e_{ii}$. And $P(e_{21})=e_{21}+e_{12}=P(e_{12})$.

Thus the matrix is $\begin{pmatrix}2&0&0&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&1&1&0\\0&0&0&2\end{pmatrix}$.

It's determinant is $0$.  Thus $P$ is not invertible.

Now try to generalize.  You can use induction.  The fact that $e_{11}$ is an eigenvector should help this go smoothly.  The first column should look like $(2,0,\dots,0)^T$. So the determinant will be $2$ times an $n-1$ minor.